# How to add a tooltip to a FLOT graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, flot, jquery-ui-tooltip

This is the full code that I am trying to use. It works without the tooltip functions but not when including them

The code produces a graph with 2 lines and bars.
How do I add a tooltip without it messing up my graph and actually add some interactivity?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You might want to consider to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Especially on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: One thing I noticed: `$("tooltip").remove();` the `#` is missing here in the selector

Comment: I just added it in, still doesn't work

Comment: Another issue: `} else(` should be `} else {`

Comment: Empiric, why did you edit my post?

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at your code in a proper IDE or use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check for further errors, there are a lot more

Comment: Regarding my edit deleting the `urgent` stuff, you may want to read this meta thread: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/4202224)

Comment: Without any of the code related to tooltip, my code works fine? I have gone through many tutorials on how to add tooltip but they still don't work for me even if they are word for word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of different errors in your fiddle:

- The grid options were missing the necessary `hoverable: true`
- Another missing `#` before placeholder in in `$("placeholder").bind("plothover", ...`
- `} else(` should be `} else {` ([from empiric's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42162226/how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-flot-graph#comment71489738_42162226))
- A superfluous `var` in `var y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);` (or replace the `,` with a `;` between the two `var` statements)
- Change `position: 'abolute'` to `position: 'absolute'` in the CSS of the tooltip

Some of the errors are found when looking at the console of your browser.

Updated working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L9gaupcu/

Comment: I can't describe how thankful I am Raidri. I have been stuck on this for ages!!